# Which Stack Exchange site should I use for clarifications on standards documents?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As I read through published standards documents (e.g., RFC 2616 ([HTTP/1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#History)), Unicode Standard, or Bluetooth 5), I have some questions about specific uses of terminology, as well as higher level concepts.

Each standards body may or may not have suggestions for ways to ask questions, but so far, my experience has been that even those who do, will not answer questions from a common reader such as myself.

Is there an appropriate Stack Exchange community for asking questions about technical standards documents?  I don't mean general questions like "What are the methods available in HTTP/1.1?"

At the moment, the question I have about RCF 2616 is:

> Section 1.3 Terminology: client vs. user agent
>
> What are some examples of a client that is not a user agent?

Comment: It would even be good to find out where to find a specific standards document or (iso) norm and/or if it includes certain sub-topics when you can’t know because it costs money (before buying).

Answer (score 3):

Specific high-level programming environment questions are on-topic at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). They may not always get the broad range of responses that generalised questions do, so be sure to describe the specific standards well and use tags to draw specialists. Unicode, HTTP, and Bluetooth have been well received and answered.

Further on in your quest, when referring to specific applications and languages, you may also consider presenting to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), asking clearly what you are missing, and writing example code where appropriate. Note not all SO questions need to be asking for a code response, whys and what-ifs can be asked well too.

Comment: Sorry but this is not really an answer to his question, if you tried at all. Simply say there is no such site yet.